# Identify different sequences with equal elements

Tags: r

I would like to get a sequence vector that is not influenced by equal values.

```
group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 )

x = c("B","B",NA,"A","B","C","D", "A","A",NA,"A","A","A", "D","A","A","D","C","D")

dad = data.frame(group, x)
```

Expected vector

```
out = c(1,1,NA,2,3,4,5, 1,1,NA,1,1,1, 1,2,2,3,4,5)

dad = cbind(dad, out)
```

That is, for example, in group `1` the element `"B"` appears again, but it must continue the sequence when there is a change in the sequence. In the cases `NA` will be `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

An option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dad)`), grouped by 'group', specify the `i` with a logical index to select only rows where 'x' is non-NA, and get the run-length-id (`rleid`) of 'x' to be assigned as new column 'ind'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dad)[!is.na(x),  ind := rleid(x), group]
dad
#    group    x ind
#1:     1    B   1
#2:     1    B   1
#3:     1 <NA>  NA
#4:     1    A   2
#5:     1    B   3
#6:     1    C   4
#7:     1    D   5
#8:     2    A   1
#9:     2    A   1
#10     2 <NA>  NA
#11:    2    A   1
#12:    2    A   1
#13:    2    A   1
#14:    3    D   1
#15:    3    A   2
#16:    3    A   2
#17:    3    D   3
#18:    3    C   4
#19:    3    D   5
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. You helped me a lot.